# Zuul routing to a mutual auth endpoint

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I was trying to set up a Zuul proxy using a Spring boot application which can either produce mock response or reaching out to an external endpoint. The communication to the external endpoint uses mutual authentication where we need to present truststore and keystore files. The implementation of `SimpleHostRoutingFilter` default route filter doesn't seem to have any implementation to present the certs in `newConnectionManager()` method.

I tried to override that method by extending `SimpleHostRoutingFilter`, but no luck.

How do we overcome this? Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Spring Cloud **Edgware** release, there is a way to provide your own HttpClient. If you are using Apache Http Client (it's default), you can create a bean of type `ClosableHttpClient`. If it is provided as a Spring Bean, `SimpleHostRoutingFilter` will be created with your own Http client. You can handle any your requirement with this.

You can find the brief note about this [here](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-netflix/1.4.0.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-netflix.html#_http_clients).

You can find the code related to this change [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/master/spring-cloud-netflix-zuul/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/zuul/ZuulProxyAutoConfiguration.java#L128).